# How to install DockerToolbox in windows without admin rights

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am following [Docker blog](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) to install DockerToolbox in windows. I fail to install because I don't have admin rights on my system.

are there any workaround to install DockerToolbox in windows without having admin rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, the installer files can be extracted using 7Zip.
Doing that with Docker Toolbox and looking at `.rsrc/VERSION/1` tells you that
`"T h i s   i n s t a l l a t i o n   w a s   b u i l t   w i t h   I n n o   S e t u p"`.

So Docker Toolbox installer for Windows is created using InnoSetup.
You can use [InnoExtract](http://constexpr.org/innoextract/) to extract it.
That gives you the files the program consists of when installed.

However you might still need Admin privileges to run it, depending on what it actually does... I haven't tried on Windows, but it will probably need to tweak the networking setup, access virtualization API and other goodies which might need the Admin rights anyway. If it was possible then I assume it would be an option for that installer.

Let me know if it worked.